# How to implement post and text_post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'd like to implement post and text_post.

```
Post: title, link, user_id
Text_post: title, body, user_id
```

Should i create two separate tables? or maybe link them together somehow? I'm new to rails:)

Answer (score 0):

They're pretty similar so you could use [Single Table Inheritance](http://eewang.github.io/blog/2013/03/12/how-and-when-to-use-single-table-inheritance-in-rails/) but if you're just starting out I'd suggest keeping it simple and straight forward and creating 2 separate tables for them.

Run this in the [command line](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html):

```
rails generate scaffold Post title:string link:string user_id:integer
rails generate scaffold TextPost title:string body:text user_id:integer
rake db:migrate
```

Those commands will generate the migrations needed to create the tables in the db, and the controllers, models, and views for you to start playing around with them.

Happy coding!

Comment: this is what i did but i thought maybe there is better way. Thanks for the link about STI though.